# How to make a home link with spry tabbed panels

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, dreamweaver, spry, panels

I have a site that mainly uses spry tabbed panels to link between pages. On the very top of the site I have a logo that I would like to use as a link to either refresh the page or take it back to the original tab. **The problem is that since I've used spry tabbed panels, the URL never changes in the site when I move from one tabbed page to another, making a 'home' link impossible.**

Does anyone know how to make a link on my site with the logo.jpeg that will refresh the page or open the original tab back up?

Here is the site:
http://emilymagnuson.com/trustbank/index.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spry Tabbed Panels are basically JavaScript. <strike>It doesn’t seem there is an easy way to hook a custom JavaScript call into the script to allow an outside element—like the logo—to trigger a tab being displayed.</strike> So I would recommend a quick & simple solution.  Wrap the logo image in a link that will reload the page completely.  So this:

```
<img src="images/logo.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

Turns into this:

```
<a href="/" target="_top"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a>
```

Or maybe this if you do not mind the `index.html` showing:

```
<a href="index.html" target="_top"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a>
```

**EDIT/CLEANER SOLUTION:** Okay, I just found [this official Adobe documentation](http://adobe.github.com/Spry/samples/tabbedpanels/tabbed_panel_sample.htm) so it seems an external JavaScript call can be done. Specifically refer to "Using Links to open tabs".  So you can do this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="TabbedPanels1.showPanel(0); return false;"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a>
```

Or do this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="TabbedPanels6.showPanel('first'); return false;"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a>
```

But I find those recommended ways of adding an `<a href>` tag clunky so I would try these instead. The image itself can be clicked without additional code but just a simple JavaScript `onclick` event:

```
<img src="images/logo.jpg" width="100" height="100" onclick="TabbedPanels1.showPanel(0); return false;">

<img src="images/logo.jpg" width="100" height="100" onclick="TabbedPanels6.showPanel('first'); return false;">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I used <img src="images/logo.jpg" width="100" height="100" onclick="TabbedPanels1.showPanel(0); return false;">